# access id within having clause rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having an issue with the HAVING clause in Rails 5.
I pull all prices for a given model, then pull all arrangements that have the provided Sku_ids.
Then I compare the sku_ids found per arrangement to the total skus in each arrangement. If they equal, then I add them to my ModelConfig 
I'm trying to find only the arrangements that contain ALL SKUs.

The issue is with the having clause. I need to reference the arrangement.id to find how many Skus are in that arrangement, but rails keeps throwing out a method undefined error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The line highlighted in the error is Arrangement.find(arrangement_id).sku_configs.count 
The issue I'm having trouble understanding is why when arrangement_id is used in .having(count(arrangement_id) = ?, it isn't able to be used in Arrangement.find(arrangement_id)

NameError in ModelConfigsController#generator > undefined local variable or method `arrangement_id' for # struct > ModelConfigJob data=:data

Thank you,

```
   Model.all.each do |model|
      CoverGrade.all.each do |cover_grade|
        @prices = Price.where(model_id: model.id).where(cover_grade_id: cover_grade.id).select(:sku_id)
        @possible_arrangements = Arrangement.joins(:sku_configs).where('sku_configs.sku_id' => @prices).group('arrangements.id')
        @actual_arrangements = []
        @possible_arrangements.having("count(arrangement_id) = ?", Arrangement.find(arrangement_id).sku_configs.count do |pa|
           @actual_arrangements << pa
        end
        if @actual_arrangements.present?
          @actual_arrangements.each do |arrangement|
            ModelConfig.create(model_id: model.id, cover_grade_id: cover_grade.id, arrangement_id: arrangement.id)
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Can you paste the error message, please?

Comment: This is what the code should look like.
@possible_arrangements.having("count(arrangement_id) = ?", Arrangement.find(arrangement_id).sku_configs.count).each
The line highlighted is Arrangement.find(arrangement_id).sku_configs.count

The issue I'm having trouble understanding is why when arrangement_id is used in .having(count(arrangement_id) = ?, it isn't able to be used in Arrangement.find(arrangement_id)

**NameError in ModelConfigsController#generator**

> undefined local variable or method `arrangement_id' for # struct
> ModelConfigJob data=:data

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in this line

```
@possible_arrangements.having("count(arrangement_id) = ?", Arrangement.find(arrangement_id))
```

`arrangement_id` doesn't seem defined here. Besides this, I don't suppose this is your intention, is it? `Arrangement.find(id)` gives you an Arrangement object, which would be interpreted to its id here. Presumably you want some number here?